# Callback function is not executed

Tags: jquery, post

The problem is that data is **successfully** transfered to the server, but the callback function is **never executed** in both versions:

```
$.post(action, formData, function (data) { alert('121'); });
```

or

```
  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: action,
           data: formData,
           dataType: "html",
           success: function(msg){
            alert('23');
           }
         });
```

JQuery 1.4.1

Thank you!

Comment: What triggers the "POST"?  Is it an event handler bound to a "click" event on an `<a>` tag? What **does** it do?

Comment: Are you verifying (via Firebug/Fiddler, etc) that a success code is being returned?

Comment: umm ... what button would that be?  What I'm driving at is this: if you've got a form, and the "click" event can trigger form submit and your event handler **doesn't** cancel event handling, then the form will go ahead and submit, ajax or no ajax.

Comment: 2Pointy: button doesn't invoke form submit, onclick event only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are generating an error? You could try switching it to a .[ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call and hook into the error handlers to see if this is occurring.

Comment: see and here I believed the **successfully** canard :-)

Answer (score 2):

take

```
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: action,
       data: formData,
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(msg){
        alert('23');
       }
     });
```

and add

```
error: function(error) {
 console.log("an error", error);
}
```

using firebug.

it may submit correctly but not receive a valid response.

Using firebug you can watch the requests going to and coming back from the server to make sure your getting what you expect and that the status code is a 200 in the Net tab.  Console.log will also output the response from the error in the console view.